# How to make one word bold in a label in ActiveReport?

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, activereports

How to make one word bold in a label in GrapeCityActiveReport 7?

For Example

**Jackson** John.

My version
ActiveReports 7
File Version      7.1.7470.0
Assembly Version  7.1.7470.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ActiveReports only the formatted text and rich text controls allow you to format the string within a single value.   Another method is to use two textboxes, one with bold font and the other without and split your fields into two values.   hope this helps.    Please contact our support team at http://activereports.grapecity.com if you need further assistance.